# mnist number classification but with your own data set

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist

This code below works perfectly fine, but I'd like to use this model with my own set of images for training and predicting, I find this model the best for my set of images since this recognizes random black lines(numbers) but im caged on the x_train and y_train part, I've got 11 different clases of my own set of images and would like to apply this model on them but I dont know how to relate them with this model, e.g:

```
train= 'C:\\Users\\min2\\Desktop\\cnn\\train'   ---> contains 11 different classes separated by folders
test= 'C:\\Users\\min2\\Desktop\\cnn\\test'     ---> contains 11 different classes separated by folders
```

I've researched what x_tain, x_test, y_train, y_test is for but im not sure how to relate muy own set of images instead of mnist set of numbers.
I think the first two parts of this code is about dealing with the set of images, and the part 3 and 4 are about the cnn model, training and predicting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

rows, cols = 28, 28

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], rows, cols, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], rows, cols, 1)

input_shape = (rows, cols, 1)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

def build_lenet(input_shape):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=6,
                                    kernel_size=(5, 5),
                                    strides=(1, 1),
                                    activation='tanh',
                                    input_shape=input_shape))
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
                                              strides=(2,2)))
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16,
                                   kernel_size=(5, 5),
                                   strides=(1, 1),
                                   activation='tanh'))
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=120, activation='tanh'))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=84, activation='tanh'))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0),
             metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

lenet = build_lenet(input_shape)

epochs = 10

history = lenet.fit(x_train, y_train,
                   epochs=epochs,
                   batch_size=128,
                   verbose=1)
loss, acc= lenet.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('ACCURACY: ', acc)

x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28)
print("Test Data", x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28)
print("Test Data", x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

image_index = 4444
plt.imshow(x_test[image_index].reshape(28, 28), cmap='Greys')

pred = lenet.predict(x_test[image_index].reshape(1, rows, cols, 1))
print(pred.argmax())
```

Comment: Would this tutorial help? Keras has a preprocessing function in TensorFlow 2.5 that can import images directly from directory: tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#load_using_keraspreprocessing

Answer (score 0):

You should change `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()` with your own dataset loader.
Use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` to load the images from the local directory or you can use `keras ImageDataGenerator` function to accomplish this.